# Seeking advice on planning to upgrade TRAC-SubVersion Server

Tags: svn, version-control, trac

this is my first post on here and i would really be grateful for any advice with my case.

I'm currently planning to upgrade our TRAC SVN Server which is currently running on `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)` it used to be on 7.1 but I have already updated that. The Server is runnning
`svnadmin, version 1.7.14 (r1542130)` & `trac-admin 1.0.1`. 
(I havn't set this one up, it was done by a former Colleague)

Everything is working perfectly fine, our R&D can work withe their repos on there and have a Project Management/Wiki at the same time. There is a LDAP integration configured somehow, Projects Permissions are linked to AD-SecGroups, so users only have access on Repos with their Domain Account if they are in a specific SecGroup.(haven't yet figured our how exactly this is working).

Since the Server was setup once and never has been touched again i would now like to upgrade it to the latest TRAC & SVN Version. Means in the first Step i just would like to Upgrade to Trac 1.2 as described here https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade#to1.2 and just install the newest SVN libraries & binaries on top of the older ones to reach SVN Version 1.13.0. Our rolled out TortoiseSVN Client would be 1.11.0, i guess 1.13.0 Server is compatible with the 1.11.0 Client or would i have to upgrade them first?

If all of this would be successful i would want to upgrade TRAC from 1.2 to 1.4 in the second Step.

Now I would just like to hear from you if you think if this is achievable like the way i'm planing to do this. Or if you have done something similar with TRAC ontop of SVN i would really like to hear your advice.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

- The Subversion 1.13 server and 1.11 client are compatible. See [Release Notes](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.13.html#compatibility).
- Make sure to [check Trac plugin compatibility](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade#a1.Checkyourplugins), if using any plugins.

Are Trac and Subversion installed on CentOS using the yum package manager? Keep in mind, unless you add a repository source in yum for Trac and Subversion, then you will have to manually manage those installations and upgrades going forward. This doesn't bother me as much for Trac as it does for Subversion.

For Trac, I would install into a Python virtual environment to give the flexibility to manage the installed packages using `pip` without polluting the global packages.